# Replacing value on one line in a text file

Tags: string, powershell, replace, text-files

I am currently working on editing one line of a text file. When I try to overwrite the text file, I only get one line back in the text file. I am trying to call the function with

```
modifyconfig "test" "100"
```

`config.txt`:

```
check=0
test=1
```

`modifyConfig()` function:

```
Function modifyConfig ([string]$key, [int]$value){
    $path = "D:\RenameScript\config.txt"

    ((Get-Content $path) | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host $_
        # If '=' is found, check key
        if ($_.Contains("=")){
            # If key matches, replace old value with new value and break out of loop
            $pos = $_.IndexOf("=")
            $checkKey = $_.Substring(0, $pos)
            if ($checkKey -eq $key){
                $oldValue = $_.Substring($pos+1)
                Write-Host 'Key: ' $checkKey
                Write-Host 'Old Value: ' $oldValue
                $_.replace($oldValue,$value)
                Write-Host "Result:" $_
            }
        } else {
            # Do nothing
        }
    }) | Set-Content ($path)
}
```

The result I receive in my `config.txt`:

```
test=100
```

I am missing "check=0".

What have I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_.replace($oldValue,$value)` in your innermost conditional replaces `$oldValue` with `$value` and then prints the modified string, but you don't have code printing non-matching strings. Because of that only the modified string are written back to `$path`.

Replace the line

```
# Do nothing
```

with

```
$_
```

and also add an `else` branch with a `$_` to the inner conditional.

Or you could assign `$_` to another variable and modify your code like this:

```
Foreach-Object {
    $line = $_
    if ($line -like "*=*") {
        $arr = $line -split "=", 2
        if ($arr[0].Trim() -eq $key) {
            $arr[1] = $value
            $line = $arr -join "="
        }
    }
    $line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or a one liner.. (not exactly pin pointed answer, but to the question title)

`(get-content $influxconf | foreach-object {$_ -replace "# auth-enabled = false" , "auth-enabled = true" })  | Set-Content $influxconf`